# how to export a 2D table in java

Tags: java

hello i would like to ask you about the 2D tables in java!!my code is this an i would like to make a system out in order t see the registrations in mytable citylink can anyone help me?

```
  int i=0;
  while(i<=citylink.length) {
    for(Xml polh_is:fetchsite.child("site").child("poleis").children("polh")) { //url 
      if((polh_is.string("name")=="")||(polh_is.content()==""))//attribute
        error += "Error in polh: name is - " + polh_is.string("name") + " with url - " + polh_is.content() + " -.\n";
      else
        for(int j=0; j<citylink.length; j++) {
          citylink[j][0]=HtmlMethods.removeBreaks(polh_is.string("name"));
          citylink[j][1]=HtmlMethods.removeBreaks(polh_is.string("with url -"+polh_is.content() +"-.\n"));

          i++;
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

citylink seems to be a single-dimensional array?
You can use another 2D array to store the values.

Comment: citylink is a 2D table but i have gave it 0 and 1 as values because i want my data to be stored like for example 00 city and 01 url of the city and as it goes!!so i want these data that i have stored them to system.out.println() them is it right to write   


System.out.println(""+citylink[j][0]);

Comment: It should work fine.
What is the exact problem you are getting?
I would suggest using another array, because of outer loop the values of previous iteration will be overridden in the next iteration of inner loop.

Comment: i m not getting any problems yet but i was confused because it is 2D table but it's not like citylink[i][j] it's cytilink[i][0] ,citylink[i][1]...so i didn't know if my thought about System.out.println(""+citylink[j][0]); was right

Comment: Yes.. you are right.  You have to use out statement in a loop

for(int j=0; j < citylink.length; j++)
   System.out.println(""+citylink[j][0]+"       "+citylink[j][1]); 


BTW, if you not getting any problems or overwhelmed with the whole code base try to write similar thing (printing out 2D array) in a sample program and you can see the behaviour of this specific snippet.

Comment: ok its fine thnx alot :) i will ask u again when i'll keep on programming

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
StringBuilder citiesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (String[] city:citylink) {
  citiesBuilder.append(String.format("%s (URL: %s)%n", city[0], city[1]));
}
System.out.println(citiesBuilder.toString());
```

**EDIT**

changed 'cities' to 'citylink' - my mistake. But trust me, it works ;) (Hope your Java is 1.5 at minimum)

ahh, and I assume, citylink is of type `String[][]`. Otherwise, please provide the declaration so I can adapt the code.

Comment: this is an answer i'm sure i would never think of!!i don't know it seems right to me!!because i don't quiet understand it i believe that it doesn't export me tha cities but only the urls!what do you think about it???i have never declared a variable as cities or city in my code there so where does it know to export me these data?

Comment: no you are right is string!!!i need this system out because i should check if i get the right values!!!this is not my holeproject just a part of it!!and belive me the other part is more complicated for my age and my knowledge!!! :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the purpose of the second for loop: is it not filling the whole array with the last element?

What about:

```
int i=0;
for(Xml polh_is:fetchsite.child("site").child("poleis").children("polh")) { //url 
  if((polh_is.string("name")=="")||(polh_is.content()==""))//attribute
    error += "Error in polh: name is - " + polh_is.string("name") + " with url - " + polh_is.content() + " -.\n";
  else if (i >= citylink.length)
     break; 
  else {
      citylink[i][0]=HtmlMethods.removeBreaks(polh_is.string("name"));
      citylink[i][1]=HtmlMethods.removeBreaks(polh_is.string("with url -"+polh_is.content() +"-.\n"));

      i++;
}
```

Comment: where do i have a second for loop???i have a if loop and if you mean this yes its not right i think i fixed it.....:) tnx alot then...

Comment: Well in your code I see three embeded loops: a while loop with a test on i, the for loop for polh_is, and a for loop on j. It seems to me that the loop on j is filling citylink with the same row. But since i is incremented inside that loop, the while loop is useless.

Another thing seems suspect to me: is the method Xml.string(String s) returning the value of an attribute? what will would be the value of polh_is.string("with url -"+polh_is.content() +"-.\n")?